# Как работает рекурсивный generic?

Tags: java, generics

У меня есть код, по которому я хочу разобраться, как работает рекурсивные generics. Смысл задачи в том, что-бы метод `compareTo`, принимал для сравнения, только объекты того типа, на котором он вызывается. То есть от класса `Product` наследуется `Milk`, и `Phone`, и объект `Phone` не должен принимать для сравнения в `compareTo`, объект `Milk`, только `Phone`. И есть место, которое я не как не могу понять. Это место `Product<T extends Product<T>>` автор кода утверждает, что для правильной работы, необходимо параметризировать  `Product<T>`. Но код работает точно так же, если написать `Product<T extends Product>`. Объясните пожалуйста, это я что-то не понимаю, или автор перемудрил. И если первое, то почему так?

```
class Product<T extends Product<T>> implements Comparable<T> { 
    private int price;

    Product(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(T o) {
        return o.getPrice() - this.price;
    }
}

class Milk extends Product<Milk> {
    Milk(int price) {
        super(price);
    }
}

class Phone extends Product<Phone> {
    Phone(int price) {
        super(price);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использование `T extends Product<T>` вместо `T extends Product` не препятствует созданию классов, у которых в качестве `T` участвует другой тип или `T` вообще не указан:

```
class Phone extends Product<Milk> { ... }

class Chair extends Product { ... }
```

Однако в случае использования `T extends Product<T>` не получится создать такой класс:

```
class CustomChair extends Product<Chair>
```

потому что это приведёт к ошибке компиляции:

> error: type argument Chair is not within bounds of type-variable T
>   class CustomChair extends Product
>     where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Product declared in class Product

Ошибка компиляции  будет даже если класс `Chair` задан так:

```
class Chair extends Product<Milk> { ... }
```

Так как в обоих случаях класс `Chair` не подходит в качестве `T` из-за требования `T extends Product<T>`. Вот `Chair extends Product<Chair>` подошло бы.

Можно сказать, что `T extends Product<T>` задаёт более жесткие условия для `T`, чем `T extends Product`. Где-то это нужно, где-то - нет.

Например, если бы в классе `Product` были такие поля:

```
private T friend, friendOfFriend;
```

и такие методы:

```
public void setFriend(T t)
{
    friend = t;
    friendOfFriend = t.getFriend();
}

public T getFriend() { return friend; }

public T getFriendOfFriend() { return friendOfFriend; }
```

То в случае использования `T extends Product` пришлось бы использовать

```
friendOfFriend = (T)t.getFriend();
```

для приведения `Product` к `T`, что чревато `ClassCastException`.
Например, при всё тех же `class Chair extends Product` и `class CustomChair extends Product<Chair>`:

```
Milk milk = new Milk(1);
Chair chair = new Chair(10);
chair.setFriend(milk);
CustomChair customChair = new CustomChair(20);
customChair.setFriend(chair);
Chair c = customChair.getFriendOfFriend();
```

В реальных условиях, надеюсь, никто не пытается подружить стул с молоком, но всё же.

С `T extends Product<T>` молоко получится подружить только с молоком:

```
Milk milk1 = new Milk(1);
Milk milk2 = new Milk(2);
Milk milk3 = new Milk(3);
milk2.setFriend(milk3);
milk1.setFriend(milk2);
Milk m = milk1.getFriendOfFriend();
System.out.println(m.getPrice());
```

Comment: я вот попробовал создать class Chair extends Product<Milk> { ... } и это компилируется хотя в родителе я использую class Product<T extends Product<T>>. Почему так?

Comment: у вас в примере говориться что запись `T extends Product<T>` не препятствует `class Phone extends Product<Milk> { ... }`, но препятствует `class Chair extends Product<Milk> { ... }` , а в чем разница почему Однако в случае использования `T extends Product<T>` не получится создать такой класс: 
class `CustomChair extends Product<Chair>` и тут же: Использование `T extends Product<T> вместо T extends Product` не препятствует созданию классов, у которых в качестве T участвует другой тип или T вообще не указан: `class Phone extends Product<Milk> { ... }`. В чем разница между ними?

Comment: @Павел нет, в ответе говорится о другом. С `class Chair extends Product<Milk>` проблем в плане компиляции нет. Проблемы возникают при использовании `class CustomChair extends Product<Chair>`, так как `Chair` не подпадает под условие `T extends Product<T>`.

Comment: а в чем разница между: `class Chair extends Product<Milk>` и `class CustomChair extends Product<Chair>`? Это же одно и тоже только названия разные. Или нет?

Comment: @Павел нет. Класс `Milk` объявлен как `class Milk extends Product<Milk>` (слева и справа `Milk`) и поэтому подходит под ограничение `T extends Product<T>`. А класс `Chair` - не подходит. Поэтому `Milk` можно в правой части `extends` использовать, а `Chair` - нельзя.

Comment: `class Milk extends Product<Milk>` это работает. Если потом написать `class Phone extends Product<Milk>` тоже все компилируется. Что же мне нужно создать что-бы была ошибка компиляции?

Comment: @Павел создайте `class SuperPhone extends Product<Phone>`.